# "operand expected" in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, math

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Users for system Alderaan: '
read 'Ald'
echo 'Users for system Coruscant: '
read 'Cor'
echo 'Users for system Endor: '
read 'End'
echo 'Users for system Hoth: '
read 'Hot'
echo 'Users for system Tatooine: '
read 'Tat'

echo SUM=$(($Ald + $Cor + $End + $Hot + $Tat))
echo AVG=$(($SUM / 5))
```

```
Users for system Alderaan: 
4
Users for system Coruscant: 
4
Users for system Endor: 
4
Users for system Hoth: 
4
Users for system Tatooine: 
4
SUM=20
./starwars: line 15: / 5: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ 5")
```

I've tried a few different ways for the "5" but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You are not setting the variable `SUM` anywhere, it only appears as an argument to `echo`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your expected output is `AVG=4`, right? You'll need to define `SUM` first. Why are you confused about that? Did you think assignment was an expression in Bash? You can [edit] to clarify if needed, and please write a proper title while you're there. Please read [ask]. Lastly, it'd help to provide a [mre]; the inputs are irrelevant to the problem so you could ignore them entirely like `echo SUM=$((4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4))`

Comment: Honestly this is my First scripting class and new to Linux and Unix. Any articles or websites you can point me too would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line ...

> ```
> echo SUM=$(($Ald + $Cor + $End + $Hot + $Tat))
> ```

... does not contain an assignment to `SUM`.  It just prints output that resembles a shell assignment.  Therefore, on the next line ...

> ```
> echo AVG=$(($SUM / 5))
> ```

... `$SUM` expands to nothing, leaving you attempting to evaluate "`/ 5`" as an arithmetic expression.

Try this instead:

```
SUM=$(($Ald + $Cor + $End + $Hot + $Tat))
echo SUM=$SUM
echo AVG=$(($SUM / 5))
```

And note that there is no assignment to `AVG`, either, but that doesn't matter because you are not attempting to use any such variable.

Comment: Hey, thanks  and i appreciate you input, I actually did a bit of digging myself and figured it out.

ans=$(($Ald+$Cor+$End))
echo Total: $ans
avg=$(($ans/5))
echo Average: $avg

Answer (score 0):

You're never setting the `SUM` variable. You're printing out (`echo`) a command which would set the `SUM` variable if you were to run that command, but you're not running that command, just printing it.

```
echo <... something ...>
```

will just print `<... something ...>`, it won't actually run `<... something ...>`. To run `<... something ...>` literally just put

```
<... something ...>
```